# VBA Working with Tables and Loops

Tags: excel, loops, resize, vba

Create a VBA loop to re-size all of the tables in an Excel project.

A list of table names is stored in the "Tlist" named range

This code all works if the table names are written in.

The code works in this loop for the column count, but on the second reference of x , the re-size, I get an error of 'subscript out of range'

Hovering over the second x on debug, Excel seems to read it in right, but I can't get it to re-size the table Something to do with the list object function not supporting the text in the loop? Or am I doing this loop wrong and need to define x differently? Any help greatly appreciated.

```
    Sub RSizeTables()
    Dim rr As Integer
    Dim cc As Integer
    Dim x As Range
    Dim £Table As Range

    Set £Table = Range("Tlist")

    For Each x In £Table

    rr = 2
    cc = Range(x).Columns.Count

    With Sheets("Data").ListObjects(x)
    .Resize .Range.Resize(rr, cc)

    End With

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you resize the tables on purpose to exactly to two rows? 2. Does Tlist contain all tables in the worksheet/workbook or only a subset?

Comment: Q1; Yes I have another snippet that deletes the data. I want them tidy - just one open row. And Yes the list has all of the tables.

Comment: Then the first code below will do - no need for `TList`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will resize all tables to two rows:

```
Sub ResizeAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject

    'If you only have tables in one sheet, use this
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    'Else this:
    'For Each ws in Sheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(2)
    Next lo
    'Next ws
End Sub
```

If you need to loop only the tables in `TList`, this will do the job:

```
Sub ResizeTList()
    Dim varTableName As Variant

    For Each varTableName In Range("TList")
        With Sheets("Data").ListObjects(varTableName)
            .Resize .Range.Resize(2)
        End With
    Next varTableName
End Sub
```